# Taking input from 3 different page forms in php and echo in 1 page

Tags: php, variables, session, input

So i have 3 pages with 3 different forms to take input, each with a submit button to save the input values in session variables and echo them all in 1 page, but i end up just printing each page output alone, how can i save the session variable so that i could print them all in 1 page from 3 different pages. Is there a form action to save the input data on clicking? or the form actions is just used to redirect to a page/file.

I have each input form in 1 php file but the output session file is 3 in 1

This is the input form:

```
 echo'<form name="Calzone" action="Submit.php" method="POST">';
      echo $P1.' :'.'<br>'.'<br>' ;
      echo 'Enter Quantity <input type="text" name="Calzone1">';

      echo '<br>';

      echo $P2.' :'.'<br>'.'<br>' ;
      echo 'Enter Quantity <input type="text"  name="Calzone2">';

  echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
```

This is to get the input from only one of the pages:

```
     <?PHP

       /*Calzones*/

       echo 'Calzones Order Details: '.'<br>'.'<br>';
       /* First Calzone*/

       foreach($xml->CategoryC as $CategoryC)
       {
        $Cprice1=$CategoryC->Calzone1->price;
        $Cprice2=$CategoryC->Calzone2->price;



        $_SESSION['Calzone1'] = isset($_POST['Calzone1']) ?$_POST['Calzone1'] : "";

        $_SESSION['Sausage Total'] = 0;
        $_SESSION['Grilled Chicken Total'] = 0;
        $_SESSION['Calzone Total'] = 0;
```

Comment: Just collect all your form input in the `$_SESSION[]=` array. Show your current code and attempts.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I understand your question, you have a *wizard-type* form.

There are a few options :

1. Store the values in sessions. You already posted code suggesting you are using sessions, so that may be great.
2. Store the values in a database and retrieve them when you need them.
3. Generate the second form with the values of form1 hidden, and so on - see the code segment below.

   foreach ($_POST as $form_field => $form_value)
      echo ';